# Php Insert Query and Email Attachment

Tags: php

hope have some help, cant find the problem, i have a script that basically what it doest is submit candidates CV forms.

When a user fill the form whit his personal information and attached his CV, the form will save the information and the cv path in database and leave the cv in a folder inside of the server, than will send a email to the company that post this job. Everything works fine, but only one problem, and this is the CV, this isnt attaching the CV in the email that is sent to the company.

Could someone take a look to the code?

```
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){


$errors= array();
foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
    $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
    $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  



    $random_digit=rand(0000,9999);

    $new_file_name=$random_digit.$file_name;

    if($file_size > 2097152){
        $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
    }       




    $query2="INSERT into candidates (`firstname`,`lastname`,`mobile`,`email`,`message`,`id_company`,`titulo_anuncio`,`job_type`,`data`,ativo) VALUES('$firstname','$lastname','$mobile','$email_candidate','$message','$id_company','$title_en','$job_type','$data','1'); ";
    mysql_query($query2);
    $user_id = mysql_insert_id();

    $query="INSERT into media (`id_candidate`,`file`,`size`,`type`) VALUES('$user_id','$new_file_name','$file_size','$file_type'); ";
    $to = $email;
    $subject = "Domainname.com | Portal of Jobs - New Candidate";

    $body = "";
    $body .= "Title Job: ";
    $body .= $title_en;
    $body .= "\n";
    $body .= "Tel: ";
    $body .= $mobile;
    $body .= "\n";
    $body .= "Email: ";
    $body .= $email_candidate;
    $body .= "\n";
    $body .= "Message: ";
    $body .= $message;
    $body .= "\n";
    $body .= "CV: ";
    $body .= "In Attachement";
    $body .= "\n";



    $headers = "From:" . $to;
     if (mail($to, $subject, $body,$headers))


    $desired_dir="candidates_cv";
    if(empty($errors)==true){
        if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
            mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
        }
        if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$new_file_name)==false){
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir/".$new_file_name);
        }else{                                  // rename the file if another one exist
            $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$new_file_name.time();
             rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
        }

     mysql_query($query);           
    }else{
            print_r($errors);
    }
}
if(empty($error)){
    echo "<span style=\"color:green;font-weight:bold;\">Submitted whit Sucess Thanks</span>";

}
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting if any?

Comment: It isn't attaching it because there is no code to support it, not with what you presently are using. Google "php file attachment". Plus, you may get better luck using PHPmailer.

Comment: It doesnt give no error, so what code is missing, cant someone fill in the rest that is missing?